# Partial View within a partial view design

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am stuck with a more fundamental question of how to approach the web page that I want to build; hence the title may not be very accurate.

The layout of my page is like below:
[image: Layout of the page I am trying to build]

What I plan is to have a main view that contains the buttons "Page 1" and "Page 2".

Within "Page 1" user can select option 1 (default selected) or "Option 2". Each option selection displays different data in the grid. So the grid I have is a partial view. And I render it so in Page 1:

```
<div id="gridContainer" class="gridContent">
  @Html.Partial("_DynamicGrid", Model)
</div>
```

I want to render Page 1 & Page 2 as partial pages within the main page. The code I have is:

```
<div id="pagesPartial" class="span10">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("Page1", Model);}
</div>
```

The page works find on load.

What I do not know how to do next is

a.) How to remove the grid and load a new one on "Option2" click

b.) How to load "Page2" view on "Page 2" button click.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I'll post what I ended up doing.

I created a partial view containing the navigation buttons on the left in the screenshot. (Page1 & Page2). And then created views for each of the pages separately rendering the navigation partial view within those views.

It was this simple and still took me time to figure out.